# PhoneGap Android Plugin - close the plugin Activity

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have written a PhoneGap Android Plugin and there I open a second activity:

```
 cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, secondActivity.class);
            cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Now I'd like to close the activity with a button and send the Plugin Result to JavaScript, but Im not able to close the activity and go back to the PhoneGap Application - how can I do this?

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your plugin, use `startActivityForResult` from CordovaInterface class instead of `startActivity` from Android:

```
this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this,intent,0);
```

(0 is a int value used to identify the activity started, use other numbers if you need to start multiple activities)

In your activity you add the following function to return a result to the plugin :

```
public void returnResult(int code, String result) {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
    setResult(code, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

So when you want to exit your activity you call this function with RESULT_CANCELED or RESULT_OK and a string representing what you want to return.

And finally in your plugin class, add the following function :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0: //integer matching the integer suplied when starting the activity
         if(resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){
             //in case of success return the string to javascript
             String result=intent.getStringExtra("result"); 
             this.callbackContext.success(result);
         }
         else{
             //code launched in case of error
             String message=intent.getStringExtra("result");
             this.callbackContext.error(message);
         }
         break;
    default:
         break;
    }
}
```

Hope it's what you were looking for.

Comment: That's what I need, but it doesn't work - I had a class Target.java, there I hava a method onClick(View v) in this method I open the return Result ('MainActivity act = new MainActivity();
act.returnResult(android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK, result);') The open of the returnResult works, but it doesn't close the actual MainActivity and the call to the onActivityResult in Plugin.java leads to the error "unfortunately App has stopped".
What's my error?

Comment: When you're in your plugin, you start your intent which instanciates MainActivity class, from there you instanciate a Target class and from this Target class you try to create a new instance of MainActivity, that's the problem. When you instanciate Target class you should pass it a ref to the MainActivity object (using constructor) and then use this ref to call returnResult instead of trying to doing new MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks, now it closes the activity but the onActivityResult isn't called.

Comment: did you use startActivityForResult to start the activity? (sorry I did a typo error yestearday and wrote startActivity in the example call, I edit it right now!)

Comment: yes I call the activity with the function posted in the first post but replaced the line "cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);" with "cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);"

Comment: sorry one more error on my side. should be `this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0);` (call cordova api's startActivityForResult, not Android's)

Comment: when I changed it to "this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0)" (instead of "cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent)") I get an error that Cordova cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I found a solution "this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this,intent,0)" works when it's not called in "cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override ...});"
QuickFix - thank your very much for your help!