# Android Phonegap 3.4: Notify javascript when an AsyncTask is finished

Tags: android, cordova, android-asynctask, phonegap-plugins

I have the same problem like Peacemoon on [Android Phonegap: Notify javascript when an AsyncTask is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751522/android-phonegap-notify-javascript-when-an-asynctask-is-finished)

Well, this works for older PhoneGap versions, but...
My problem: This doesn't work on newer PhoneGap Version like PhoneGap 3.4.

The plugin class inherit from CordovaPlugin now and the return type of execute method is boolean now and the parameter is CallbackContext instead int callbackId and so on. How can I realize an asynchron Task now?

My approach:

```
private CallbackContext myCallbackContext;

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, 
    final CallbackContext callbackId)
{
    this.myCallbackContext = callbackId;
    if (action.equals("test"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.companyname.name.TEST");
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, 0);

         // create an empty result, because the asynchronous call can take long
        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        this.myCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

        this.myCallbackContext.success;

        return true;
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bundle korb = intent.getExtras();
            String osVersion = korb.getString("osVersion");


            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
             try
             {
                 obj.put("osVersion", osVersion);
             } catch(JSONException e)
             {
                 // Log
             }
PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, obj);
             result.setKeepCallback(false);
             this.myCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);

             this.myCallbackContext.success(obj);
}
```

My return to JavaScript is undefined. But it works in my old version with an older PhoneGap version like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751522/android-phonegap-notify-javascript-when-an-asynctask-is-finished) . How does it work on a newer PhoneGap version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My MainActivity implements CordovaInterface since newer versions of Cordova/PhoneGap. So it is necessary to implement the method "startActivityForResult". If I called "this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, 0)", the scope is set on the MainActivity, and the Call of the new intent is going over the method "startActivityForResult" in MainActivity. So, the result comes back to "onActivityResult" in the MainActivity. Here I have to call my method in the plugin:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    Log.d("Debug", "-----> MainActivity: onActivityResult");
    if(this.activityResultCallback != null)
    {
        // this is the solution :)
        this.activityResultCallback.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }
}
```

Additionally, the intent call work for both:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.cordova.getActivity(), com.companyname.name.TestActivity.class);
if (this.cordova != null) {
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0);
    return true;
}
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.companyname.name.TEST");
if (this.cordova != null) {
    this.cordova.startActivityForResult((CordovaPlugin) this, intent, 0);
}

<!--you must add the String to the AndroidManifest.xml-->
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="de.companyname.name.TEST" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Otherwise (how QuickFix described) in the exute method I have to use 'return true' or 'return false', if an error occured. And in the onActivityResult method I have to use 'myCallbackContext.success(obj);'. Nothing else. I don't need something like 'this.myCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what what my plugin class for phonegap 3.x looks like:

```
    public CallbackContext callbackContext;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

        if (action.equals("anAction")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(),com.companyname.name.TEST.class);
            if (this.cordova != null) {
                this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, intent, 0);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        //retour de la version utilisant le sample de imense alpr
         if(resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){ //0:ok      
             String result=intent.getStringExtra("result"); 
             this.callbackContext.success(result);
         }
         else{
             String message=intent.getStringExtra("result");
             this.callbackContext.error(message);
         }

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This dosen't work for me.
My com.companyname.name.TEST Activity was not called yesterday. Some methods were empty or return null in my MainActivity with the exception of: 
@Override 
public Activity getActivity() {
 return this;
} 
Today I added code to these methods like the code in the CordovaActivity.java file in framewokk/src of cordova. So, my com.companyname.name.TEST Activity is called. But onActivityResult is not called.
My code above is in the TestPlugin class wich extend from CordovaPlugin.
My MainActivity extends from Activity and implements CordovaInterface.

Comment: You do not need to do any change to the main activity of the cordova app to make a plugin work, just to the class that extends the CordovaPlugin class and here the activity you're starting by intent. Do you call setResult(resultcode,intent) and finish() when you want to exit com.companyname.name.TEST?

Comment: Check my answer in this other post, maybe it will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858861/phonegap-android-plugin-close-the-plugin-activity

Comment: Yes, I call setResult and finish. My Code was working on PhoneGap 2.1, but not with 3.4.
I add the onActivityResult method in the MainActivity and this is called now. But so I have no way back to the CordovaWebView/JavaScript.

Comment: I updated my code sample to look more like what I really have in my code. The difference is tht I use the constructor Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls) to create the intent and passing it this.getActivity() as a context. Maybe that's what makes that the plugin's onActivityResult is called after finish.

Comment: Cannot resolve method getActivity.
What is your surrounding class look like?
For me, it is public class TestPlugin extends CordovaPlugin.

Comment: getActivity is a getter I add in all my plugin classes. It just returns `this.cordova.getActivity();` so you can just use this instead.

Comment: I have the solution. Look for it below in a moment. Thanks for you help QuickFix. It set me on the right way.