# Cordova Plugin Stop/Restart Activity

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova plugin which uses the https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video example. I would like to disable the back button while in Camera.

To do this, I believe Fragments can't accept back button events, so have added an Activity to the plugin. I can successfully run the plugin, camera and activity, disabled the back button.

However when I close the plugin it errors with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

To get around this I have used `commitAllowingStateLoss` instead of `commit` however when I open the plugin the second time, it errors with:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.app.Activity org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface.getActivity()' on a null object reference
```

I presume I'm not stopping the activity correctly, and allowing the state to be lost, which causes a second error. How do I get around this?

I've tried this method but no luck:
[PhoneGap Android Plugin - close the plugin Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858861/phonegap-android-plugin-close-the-plugin-activity)

I've put my code in a branch here:
https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom/tree/feature/back-button

Add a summary of the changes:

plugin.xml

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:name="com.example.android.camera2video.MediaCustomActivity" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</config-file>
<source-file src="src/android/MediaCustom.java" target-dir="src/com/example/android/camera2video" />
<source-file src="src/android/MediaCustomActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/example/android/camera2video" />
<source-file src="src/android/Camera2VideoFragment.java" target-dir="src/com/example/android/camera2video" />
```

MediaCustom.java

```
public void show() {
    if (cameraFragment != null) {
        return;
    }
    cameraFragment = Camera2VideoFragment.newInstance(cordova, callbackContext);
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            cordova.getActivity().setContentView(resources.getIdentifier("activity_camera", "layout", packageName));
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = cordova.getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(resources.getIdentifier("container", "id", packageName), cameraFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            MediaCustomActivity.start(cordova.getActivity());
        }
    });
}

public void hide() {
    if (cameraFragment == null) {
        return;
    }
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MediaCustomActivity.stop(cordova.getActivity());

            cordova.getActivity().setContentView(getView());
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = cordova.getActivity().getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(cameraFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); // commit();
            cameraFragment = null;
        }
    });
}
```

MediaCustomActivity.java

```
public static void start(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MediaCustomActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void stop(Activity activity) {
    // what can we do here?
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```